On the conversion of a 3rd-order Recurrence Relation to 2nd-order
In a recent post I inadvertently discovered that the sequence A000325 can be represented by a homogeneous 3rd-order recurrence. I subsequently showed that this could be transformed into an inhomogeneous 2nd-order one. The OEIS has no mention of recurrence relations, just the sequence $f_n=2^n-n$. Here is what I did.
I was looking at OEIS A000325 and trying to reverse engineer a homogeneous 2nd-order recurrence. This was not successful, but an attempt at a 3rd-order was. Basically, in both cases I set up the requisite number of equations for the unknowns and solved for the recurrence coefficients with Cramer's rule. Thus, I found for OEIS A000325
$$
f_n=Af_{n-1}+Bf_{n-2}+Cf_{n-3}\\
$$
where $[A, B, C]=[4, -5, 2]$.
The inspiration for converting this to 2nd-order comes from the trick of converting an inhomogeneous 1st-order recurrence to homogeneous 2nd-order one as follows.
Consider a general 2nd-order recurrence with a constant inhomogeneous term. We will decrement the recurrence and subtract from the original to eliminate the constant,
$$
\begin{align}
&f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}+c\\
&f_{n-1}=af_{n-2}+bf_{n-3}+c\\
&-------------------\\
&f_n=(a-1)f_{n-1}+(b-a)f_{n-2}-bf_{n-3}
\end{align}
$$
Comparing with the 3rd-order recurrence above we find
$$
\begin{matrix}
A=a+1 & \quad & a=A-1\\
B=b-a & \quad & b=-C=B+A-1\\
C=-b & \quad & c=f_2-af_1-bf_0
\end{matrix}
$$
Clearly, this transformation is valid only when $A+B+C=1$, as it is for OEIS A000325.
Finally, we can solve this recurrence by the usual methods, such as
$$
f_n=g_n+R\cdot n
$$
where $g_n$ is the homogeneous solution with $g_0=f_0$ and $g_1=f_1-R$, and $R=c/(a+2b)$. We find that $f_n=2^n-n$, in complete agreement with OEIS A000325.
My questions are whether this has been done previously and how it may have been
done otherwise.
